# Why can I not return the correct variables?

Tags: vb.net, return

I'm having trouble returning the correct value for the subtotal in my application.  The user selects the type of tour they want, and enters the number of tickets to be purchased.  After pressing the Calculate Cost button, the subtotal, tax amount, and final total are displayed.

My code for the subtotal methods and btnCost_Click is below:

```
Private Sub btnCost_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCost.Click
    Dim intTicketQuantity As Integer
    Dim blnNumberOfTicketsIsValid As Boolean = False
    Dim blnCheckForRad As Boolean = False
    Dim decSubTotal As Decimal
    Dim decTotalTax As Decimal
    Dim intTourType As Integer

    blnNumberOfTicketsIsValid = ValidateNumberOfTickets()

    If (blnNumberOfTicketsIsValid) Then
        intTicketQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(txtTickets.Text)
        intTicketQuantity = cboTourType.SelectedIndex
        If (intTicketQuantity > 0) Then
            intTourType = cboTourType.SelectedIndex
        End If

        Select Case intTourType
            Case 0
                decSubTotal = Story(intTourType, intTicketQuantity)
                decTotalTax = Tax(decSubTotal)
            Case 1
                decSubTotal = Battleground(intTourType, intTicketQuantity)
                decTotalTax = Tax(decSubTotal)
            Case 2
                decSubTotal = Mission(intTourType, intTicketQuantity)
                decTotalTax = Tax(decSubTotal)
        End Select
        ShowAll(decSubTotal, decTotalTax)
    End If
End Sub

Private Function Story(ByVal intTourType As Integer, intTicketQuantity As Integer) As Decimal
    Dim decSubTotal As Decimal = 0D

    If (radWeekday.Checked = True) Then
        decSubTotal = 19D * intTicketQuantity * (1 - _decDiscount)
    ElseIf (radWeekend.Checked = True) Then
        decSubTotal = 19D * intTicketQuantity
    End If
    Return decSubTotal
End Function

Private Function Battleground(ByVal intTourType As Integer, intTicketQuantity As Integer) As Decimal
    Dim decSubTotal As Decimal = 0D

    If (radWeekday.Checked = True) Then
        decSubTotal = 29D * intTicketQuantity * (1 - _decDiscount)
    ElseIf (radWeekend.Checked = True) Then
        decSubTotal = 29D * intTicketQuantity
    End If
    Return decSubTotal
End Function

Private Function Mission(ByVal intTourType As Integer, intTicketQuantity As Integer) As Decimal
    Dim decSubTotal As Decimal = 0D

    If (radWeekday.Checked = True) Then
        decSubTotal = 49D * intTicketQuantity * (1 - _decDiscount)
    ElseIf (radWeekend.Checked = True) Then
        decSubTotal = 49D * intTicketQuantity
    End If
    Return decSubTotal
End Function
```

Comment: `intTicketQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(txtTickets.Text)`
        `intTicketQuantity = cboTourType.SelectedIndex` Why do you assign this variable twice both to different values, right next to each other?

Comment: What result are you expecting, and how does the actual result differ from the expected result? Not everyone who would like to help you, has the time to open a new VB.NET project, create appropriate UI elements and copy and paste your code in order to figure out the intention.

Comment: Get rid of `intTicketQuantity = cboTourType.SelectedIndex`

Comment: Thank you, topshot, that was the problem.  I removed that line and it worked perfectly.